# How to make variables in URL look like the permalink structure?

Tags: permalinks, variables

I've been looking for the answer to this everywhere but with no success and that's why I'm asking here.

I don't even know if the question is the right one.

In any case, I'll try to explain.

I have a WordPress page with variables in the URL, like this: http://planeta-beisbol.com/tal-dia-como-hoy/?dia=18&mes=04

The content changes depending on the day and month of the year because is gathered from the databse.

My question is: How can I change the URL to look something like **planeta-beisbol.com/tal-dia-como-hoy/dia/18/mes/04** or **planeta-beisbol.com/tal-dia-como-hoy/18/04**

Any help is apreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have a couple questions that may help someone else answer this better. In your link structure do you mean something like this: `planeta-beisbol.com/` `tal` = tagname? - `dia` = tagname? -como-hoy/`dia` = category? `/18/mes/04` D/M/Y? or would it be `planeta-beisbol.com/` `tal-dia-como-hoy` post name? / `dia` CPT/Category/Term `/18/mes/04` D/M/Y Identifying these may help someone better help you with building your Query

Comment: "tal-dia-como-hoy" is the page name, something like "this date in history". Meaning: planeta-beisbol.com/tal-dia-como-hoy ... This page has some code that takes from the variables in the URL to pull content, which is based on the current day and month, but also the visitors can choose any other date to read some historic happenings in baseball ... I would like to have the URL in permalink form rather than "?dia=18&mes=04" ("dia" means day, and "mes" means month")

Comment: If it's easier to make a template of it instead of a standard page, that would be fine with me... Thanks for answering Dave, I hope what I've said could clear things. English is not my mother language, sorry.

Comment: Frank, I hope you've gotten a little closer. I only asked because sometimes it's easy for anyone to misinterpret what is asked. There's a few options out there for rewriting but it looks like you're on the right track with the answer below ;)

Answer (score 1):

The following two functions should point you in the right direction:

```
function wpse49393_query_vars($query_vars)
{
    $query_vars[] = 'myvar';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'wpse49393_query_vars');

function wpse49393_rewrite_rules_array($rewrite_rules)
{
    $rewrite_rules['path/to/page/([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?pagename=path/to/page&myvar=$matches[1]';
    return $rewrite_rules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'wpse49393_rewrite_rules_array');
```

I would give credit where it is due, but I cannot remember where I originally found this code. I just pulled this out of a project that I am currently working on. To use it, change `myvar` to the name of your variable in the first function as well as here: `&myvar=$matches[1]`. Change `path/to/page/` to the actual path of your page at two locations in the second function.

Comment: OK, so far I got this code: `code function add_directory_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_tag("%dia%", '(.+)');
    add_rewrite_tag("%mes%", '(\d+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^tal-dia-como-hoy/(.+)/(\d+)', 'index.php?p=3393/?dia=$matches[1]&mes=$matches[2]', 

'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_directory_rewrite' ); code` and for testing, I got this code in my page: `code` echo get_query_var("dia").'/'.get_query_var("mes"); `code` In my page it retreaves correctly "18/04" but if I follow this URL "planeta-beisbol.com/tal-dia-como-hoy/18/04" it sends me straight to my homepage

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to display code here

Comment: Remove that code and try what I suggested.

Answer (score -1):

You can do you're own custom permalink structures, have you looked here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks?

Comment: Thanks Alex, I've read the codex but still can't find the solution. They explain the permalinks for pages and posts but not for custom GET variables in the URL...

Comment: I got it working now, thanks to this post: http://zagar.biz/2011/wordpress-creating-custom-permalinks/

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to this post for the heads up: http://zagar.biz/2011/wordpress-creating-custom-permalinks/

My final code ended up being like this:

**In the theme's functions.php file**

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','mycode_add_rewrite_rules');

// Add all rewrite rules here
// ** Remember to Flush Rewrite rules when adding new rules.
// this is done by visiting the Settings > Permalinks in WP admin.

function mycode_add_rewrite_rules($rules){
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['tal-dia-como-hoy/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?'] = 'index.php?pagename=tal-dia-como-hoy&dia=$matches[1]&mes=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

add_filter('query_vars','mycode_add_rewrite_query_vars');

// Add all slugs so that WP recognizes it
function mycode_add_rewrite_query_vars($vars){
    array_push($vars, 'dia');
    array_push($vars, 'mes');
    return $vars;
}
```

Then, in **the page I created**. This is just a regular wordpress page, not a template or anything like that

```
global $wp;

// connect to your external DB, etc...

if($wp->query_vars["dia"]){

echo "Permalinks are working";
    // load up your external data here and display single resource
        // if the beard slug doesn't exist, redirect to 404
} else {
    // load up whatever you want to display for the index version.
echo "Nothing shows up but it's working anyway";
}
```

I have to edit the page to make it look good with my brand new permalinks.

This is the page I'll using with this code: http://planeta-beisbol.com/tal-dia-como-hoy/19/04/

The "19/04" part means: 19th of April

I hope this code is useful for everybody

Comment: That code is pretty much what I suggested in the first place. Why did you ignore me?

Comment: I agree with @Joseph